# Is there any way to perform operations with input data?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, split

I want to take a string as an input which will contain operation and the data. Can I run that command with the string provided.

For example:

Here I'm asking a user for input twice and will execute the operation with the data.

```
new_list = []
for i in range(2):
    data = input().split()     # data = "append 1" , data = "append 2"
    new_list.data[0](data[1])  # new_list.append(1) , new_list.append(1)
print(new_list)
```

In above program I'm executing operation `append` given by user where `data = "append 1"` when `i = 0` and `data = "append 2"` when `i = 1`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm presuming that the first argument will always be a function of an object. You can use `getattr()` to get the append method.

```py
data = input().split()
getattr(new_list, data[0])(data[1]) # Case data[1] to an int or another type if needed
```

See the [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) docs!